# Powershell script not executing through Asp.net web page

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell

Powershell script works perfectly fine, when i run through command windows. But through asp.net web page it doesn't. Can anyone give pointers for troubleshooting ... running windows 10

```
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;

            Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
            runspace.Open();
            Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
            pipeline.Commands.AddScript("powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -file D:\\Files\\Scripts\\Script20180817.ps1 -FilePath " + file);
            pipeline.Invoke();
            runspace.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AddScript` expects code.  You can remedy this by reading the script into memory, passing it, then using `AddParameter` to pass the `-FilePath`.  You're not doing anything fancy with the runspaces, so I reduced the code for readability:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Management.Automation;

string scriptPath = @"D:\Files\Scripts\Script20180817.ps1";
string file = "TBD?";

string script = File.ReadAllText(scriptPath);
using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
{
    ps.AddScript(script).AddParameter('FilePath', file);
    ps.Invoke();
}
```